# Error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: RNSVGsvgView

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I have encountered this error after installing `react-native-svg`. I have all svg icons in a separate `.js` file and calling them as follows,

```
<Icons name={'dot'} style={{height:4, width:4, marginRight:10}} color={"#D8D8D8"}/>
```

as per this [Solution](http://Error%20while%20updating%20property%20%E2%80%9Cwidth%E2%80%9D(or%20other)%20in%20shadow%20node%20of%20type%20:%20RCTIMage%20View), What ever the values I have given in style object are integers only. But still I am facing this error.

As per this [git Solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21002), some one is asking to downgrade and some one is asking to upgrade react native. But not sure which one gives permanent fix to this error.

Can somebody please let me know root cause of the error and permanent fix for this.
Thank You.

Comment: @RobertLongson didn't get what do you mean by missing units

Comment: @RobertLongson getting an error if try to give such an units.  here 10 means 10dip.` react-native` supports only Density-independent Pixel

Answer (score 1):

as i know this issue happens when you set width and height style to Icon component

you should set `size` prop to `<Icon />`

your code should be Like this :

```
<Icons name={'dot'} size={15} style={{marginRight:10}} color={"#D8D8D8"}/>
```

Comment: As per `react-native-svg`, there is no such a prop `size`. And moreover this issue not only happens with `height` or `Width`, but also with  `margin` (`marginTop` or `marginBottom` etc...)

Comment: try add a view as parent and set styles to parent view

Comment: As you said, we can set height, width or margins to view. But I have recently faced an error `Error while updating property 'fill' of a view managed by: RNSVGPath
`. So wrapping in a view may not be a right solution for these issues. Can you suggests something else to prevent these issues?